# Quagga OSPFv3 does not update IPv6 routes

Tags: networking, routing, ipv6, ospf, quagga

NOTE: I've posted this on SuperUser but reposting here because I think it may be more suitable.

I'm trying to configure Quagga to use OSPFv3 to create proper IPv6 routes between two OpenWrt routers running OpenVPN (tun mode). I know the tunnel is working properly because it works if I configure the routes manually.

Both routers have a link-local address on the tun0 interface, and I can actually see OSPFv3 packets between the routers, but the routes are not being set-up in the routing table. I would also like to point out that OSPFv2 does work so this is probably not a permission issue.

I'm attaching the ospf6d.conf files from both routers, I'd appreciate any insights regarding possible misconfiguration.

OpenVPN server side:

```
hostname gateway
password *********
enable password *********
log file /tmp/zebra-ospf6d.log

!
!
!
interface default
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface br-lan
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface eth0
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface eth0.1
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface lo
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface pppoe-wan
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface tun0
  no ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface wlan0
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface tun1
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface tun2
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!

router ospf6
  router-id 192.168.92.2
  redistribute kernel
  interface br-lan area 0.0.0.0
  interface tun0 area 0.0.0.0
  interface tun1 area 0.0.0.0
  interface tun2 area 0.0.0.0
  area 0.0.0.0 range 2000::/3
  area 0.0.0.0 range fc00::/7
!
line vty
!
end
```

OpenVPN client side:

```
hostname gateway
password *********
enable password *********
log file /tmp/zebra-ospf6d.log


!
!
!
interface default
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface br-lan
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface eth0
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface eth0.1
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface lo
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface pppoe-wan
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface tun0
  no ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface tun1
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface wlan0
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface wlan1
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!

router ospf6
  router-id 192.168.92.1
  redistribute kernel
  interface br-lan area 0.0.0.0
  interface tun0 area 0.0.0.0
  interface tun1 area 0.0.0.0
  area 0.0.0.0 range 2000::/3
  area 0.0.0.0 range fc00::/7
!
line vty
!
end
```

Thank you!

Comment: Setting an interface to passive means that it will not participate in OSPF. If you make all the interfaces passive, then you will not create neighbors on any of them. You only make an interface passive when you know there are no OSPF neighbors on the interface. You could, instead, use the `passive interface default` router command, and then use the `no passive interface <interface>` router command to be able to create neighbors on a particular interface.

Comment: Only the tun0 interface has OSPF neighbors and it's set to no passive